# Shall we hold a Community Wiki for all the "official" sites?

Tags: discussion

Android has a lot of developers and most of them are enthusiatic. They develop good stuff like Magisk and Xposed but don't care about marketing, and therefore such applications don't have good-looking official websites. This gives scammers chances to build websites "for" those apps and advertise or even spam them, for example [here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&body=vancedtube.com)'s some spam records of a fake website for YouTube Vanced. Very unintuitively, the official website for YTV is https://vanced.azurewebsites.net/ (seen on [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-youtube-vanced-edition-t3758757)), which doesn't even turn up on the first page of Google result. Similar things also happens for Lucky Patcher (doesn't have its own domain) or Magisk (doesn't have a website at all), etc. Fortunately, apps like Titanium Backup or (previously) SuperSU that are available from Google Play can be easily verified.

Shall we create our list of official websites for those ncie stuff whose websites are often mistaken or surpassed by spammers?

Comment: Shouldn't those rather be in the corresponding tag wikis? A question like "what are the official URLs" should, according to our rules, be closed as requesting off-site resources ;)

Comment: @Izzy Ah, yes. Tag wikis sounds like a better place for these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Summing up from the comments:</sup>

A question asking for "(official) links" would, per definition, be asking for "off-site resources" and thus be off-topic – even if canonical. Best place for such links are the corresponding tag-wikis (if such exist; in the most (important) cases they do – else add them).

And while it's true that tag wikis are ignored much too often (mostly as people are unaware of them), they are not harder to find than any (canonical) question – in fact they are even easier to find whenever the tag is used.

Comment: OK, I'll start suggesting edits to tag wikis to add the links.